# i need to break references in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

i have two arrays, at the begining one is empty and i assign what is in the other to this empty array. Something like this. `$scope.module_Allquestions = $scope.module_questions.questions;`

What i need to know is if there is some way to break references between two arrays, i'm working in some project in angular js. So i know that in es6 we can you spread operator. But i was told that in angular js that is behind es6 i can't use it. Do you know any way on how to make those arrays not referenced?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `Array.from(arr)` as an alternative, or `arr.slice()`.

Comment: Always a good idea to [check compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#browser_compatibility) for things like this. Do you really need to support IE11?

Comment: I don't need support for that

Answer (score 2):

> But i was told that in angular js that is behind es6 i can't use it

You were told wrong. Angular is just a JS library. You can use spread syntax if the JS engine you are running on supports it. (Which is basically "Anything except IE 11" and even then you can transpile it to ES5).

Other options include `Array.from(scope.module_questions.questions)` and `scope.module_questions.questions.slice()` for shallow copies and the [Immer library](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) for dealing with more complex data structures (such as when you have an array of objects).

Comment: Ok, i tried with spread operator then, the functionality is working as expected. But my problem now is that when i execute tests with grunt karma:ci, it says this: 08 03 2022 12:40:25.957:ERROR [preprocessor.coverage]: Line 586: Unexpected token ...

And line 586 is where i use spread operator.

Comment: That suggests your build system is either using Node.js older than v5 (which is unsupported and you should upgrade) or there is a problem with some linting feature somewhere in your test libraries.

Comment: So there is no way through, this is an old big project and also a lot of people to talk with in order to upgrade. So well, i'll try with the other options.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your contents, you could go for a copy strategy such as `$scope.module_Allquestions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.module_questions.questions));`